# How to use \tag{} for multiple equation in align*

Tags: equations, tags

I am working on a report. One of that is to requote many equations from paper. I often use:

```
\begin{align*}\tag{5}
x = a + b
\end{align*}
```

This works fine for a single equation. However, is there any way to tag many equations in a single \align*, instead of working manually like:

```
\begin{align*}\tag{5}
x = a + b
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\tag{10}
y = c + d
\end{align*}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost: don't use `align` for single equations.

Second: `align` is for multiline displays.

```latex
\begin{align}
x &= a+b \tag{*} \\
y &= c+d \tag{**}
\end{align}
```

You say you have to repeat equations. Then you shouldn't use an explicit number.

```latex
%%% in section 1
\begin{equation}\label{important}
x=a+b
\end{equation}

%%% in section 3
\begin{equation}\tag{\ref{important}}
x=a+b
\end{equation}
```

The same with `align`.